# Variables confusion

Tags: c, variables, loops, memory-management, malloc

I must read more elements P in a function.
Is it better to create pElem  every time in a loop?

```
dataStr *  process(char *start, char *stop, GTree* tree)
{
  while ( (cp != NULL) && ( cp   < nextI))
  {
      //I malloc inside of getPElem function
      pElem * p = getPElem(cp, dateP, s);
      free(p);
  }
}
```

Or should I better initialize once P-element  and reuse it every time?

```
dataStr *  process(char *start, char *stop, GTree* tree)
{
  pElem * p = malloc(sizeof(p));
  while ( (cp != NULL) && ( cp   < nextI))
  {
      fillPElem(p, cp, dateP, s);

  }
  free(p);
}
```

If one element would be better, should I malloc it one outside the function (function "process" is called in a loop too):

```
dataStr *  process(char *start, char *stop, GTree* tree, pElem * p )
{

  while ( (cp != NULL) && ( cp   < nextI))
  {

       fillPElem(p, cp, dateP, s);

  }      
}
```

Or every time inside the function like in the second example?

Comment: the two first snippets you posted are supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: For me, `malloc` in a loop is not very optimized. If you use it only like a buffer, you should do only one `malloc`.

Comment: Yes, all snippets are supposed to be equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the pElems to live longer than the enclosing scope, there's no need to dynamically allocate at all:

```
dataStr *  process(char *start, char *stop, GTree* tree)
{
  pElem p;
  while ( (cp != NULL) && ( cp   < nextI))
  {
      fillPElem(&p, cp, dateP, s);

  }
}
```

(yes, I know that none of cp, nextI etc. are defined - I just copied from the question).

Comment: So , won't it be better to allocate it outside of the function and give it as a param?

Comment: I can't answer that without some hint about how you're intending to use it. None of your original functions expose the element outside the function at all.

Comment: I don't need it at all outside. The only reason why I did ask about it is, that the function process is called in a loop. So I get new pElem p every time. I thought, I can also initialize it once outside. I really duno what is better so that why I have asked. Your solution is much more 'natural'.

Comment: declaring the variable doesn't initialize it though, it just reserves some space on the stack.

Comment: Sorry, that was what I mentioned. Now it reserves and frees all the time.

Comment: stack allocation has negligible cost compared to dynamic allocation, and you're probably building a stack frame for the function call anyway. Don't worry about it until you need to allocate something *huge*

Comment: ok, so is it generally good(or better) to use  local variables  `pElem p` instead of mallocating the memory like `pElem p = malloc(sizeof(p))`? I have removed all malloc now(I replaced every one that i had with local declaration).